# Remove right side of box-shadow - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div having a box-shadow. I would like to remove the right-side of it but would not like to add any new code however can modify the existing box-shadow property. I used clip-path but I want it to work on IE as well.Please advice.

```css
.test1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.6), 0 0 0 rgba(138, 155, 168, 0), 0 1px 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.3);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">MY AWESOME CONTENT</div>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the shadow to the left till it is behind the element as so ...

```css
.test1 {
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.6), 0 0 0 rgba(138, 155, 168, 0), 0 1px 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.3);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">MY AWESOME CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: Why is the left-border a tad thick? Can I have the same thickness all over the div?

Comment: The left border is 2px because we moved the whole shadow 1px to the left.
I don't think you can have it the same thickness with the above solution could you not just do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r7san528/7/ ???

Answer (score 1):

use an extra white shadow that will hide the one you don't need:

```css
.test1 {
  box-shadow: 
   1px 0 1px #fff,
   0 0 0 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.6), 
   0 1px 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.3);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">MY AWESOME CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, very concise, as long as you know the background behind the portion of the box shadow you wish to hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
.test1 {
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.6), 0 0 0 rgba(138, 155, 168, 0), 0 1px 1px rgba(138, 155, 168, 0.3);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

This appears to do the trick as far as I can tell. The latter two box shadows don't appear to do anything however. If you're just looking for a border, there are better ways to do it.